# The type ExceptionPolicyImpl has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate

Tags: wcf, enterprise-library

I've a WCF service configured with Enterprise Library 5 "Logging Application Block", "Validation Application Block Integration with WCF" and "Exception Handling Application Block WCF Provider" and configured it using fluent API like this:

```
 builder.ConfigureExceptionHandling()
            // -----------------------------------------------------
            // Preventing Enterprise Library Validation Block exceptions from getting shielded.
            // -----------------------------------------------------
            .GivenPolicyWithName("WCF Exception Shielding")
            .ForExceptionType<FaultException<ValidationFault>>()
            .ThenDoNothing()

            // -----------------------------------------------------
            // Shielding unhandled exceptions
            // -----------------------------------------------------
            .ForExceptionType<Exception>()
            .LogToCategory("My Logging Category")
            .WithSeverity(TraceEventType.Critical)
            .ShieldExceptionForWcf(typeof(ServiceUnhandledFault), Resources.UnhandledException_ErrorMessage)
            .ThenThrowNewException();
```

Service Implementation:

```
[ServiceContract]
[ValidationBehavior]
[ExceptionShielding("WCF Exception Shielding")]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ValidationFault))]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ServiceUnhandledFault))]
    void InsertEntity(MyEntity file);
}

[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public partial class MyService : IMyService { ...Implementation... }
```

If I set the "IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults" property of my service debug behavior to false and call a service operation with an entity that won't validate correctly the following exception will be thrown in the service:

> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl", name = "WCF Exception Shielding".
>   Exception occurred while: while resolving.
>   Exception is: **InvalidOperationException - The type ExceptionPolicyImpl has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate.**

But if I set the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults to true a validation fault will be returned to the client.

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to configure Ent Lib with Fluent API approach.  I had similar error when I was trying configure Ent Lib with BOTH configuration files (web.config) and fluent api.  If yes, you might try removing the config file variables and do only with fluent api.  I found that this resolved the error for me.
Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I was trying configure _Ent Lib 4.1_ for a *Old app .net 3.5 clr 2.0 appPool* and _Ent Lib 5.0_ for a *New app .net 4.5 clr 4.0 appPool* with BOTH configuration files (web.config) , and I get the same error.